# Angular - Can't access controller methods after compiling directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wysiwyg

I am heavily modifying a WYSIWYG js plugin, and am inserting my own custom elements into it.
To insert the custom elements, I am using directives so that they can be easily maintained if I need to make a change. Here is an example of my code so far:

The initial load of the wysiwyg editor:

```
<div ng-controller="wyswiygCtrl">
    <textarea wysiwyg-editor ng-model="content"></textarea>
</div>
```

Here is an example of a custom element (directive) I am inserting into the wysiwyg content:

```
<wysiwyg-element class="custom_element" name="awesome" type="checkbox" checked="true"></wysiwyg-element>
```

I am using the following code within the directive's initialisation, to compile any custom elements (directives) within it:

```
var e = angular.element(wysiwygEditor.get(0).innerHTML);
$compile(e.contents())(scope);
wysiwygEditor.html(e);
```

It compiles the directives just as I need it to, but here comes the tricky part. I need to be able to call a function within the 'wysiwygCtrl' from OUTSIDE angular. I am able to do this before compiling, but for some reason, after using angular's compile function, I can't access the scope on the elements.

Here is the code which works before a `$compile`:

```
angular.element($('.custom_element')).scope().wysiwygModal();
angular.element($('.custom_element')).scope().$apply();
```

I get the following error after trying to call the `wysiwygModal` function after a $compile:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'wysiwygModal'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to access the `scope()` and its variables on a compiled element.  Could you edit this plunkr or create your own if this doesn't help?

http://plnkr.co/edit/kvbvKXeVjEhmeE7257ly?p=preview

**script.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myEditor', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
    },
    template: 
      '<div>' + 
        '<h3>Raw HTML</h3>' + 
          '<textarea rows=5 cols=40 ng-model="text"></textarea>' + 
        '</div>' + 
        '<hr />' +
        '<div>' + 
          '<h3>Compiled HTML</h3>' + 
          '<div my-preview></div>' + 
        '</div>' +  
        '<hr />' +
        '<div>' + 
          '<h3>Messages generated during compilation</h3>' + 
          '<div ng-repeat="message in messages">[{{message}}]</div>' + 
        '</div>' + 

      '</div>',
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.messages = [];

      this.getText = function () {
        return $scope.text;
      };

      this.addMessage = function (message) {
        $scope.messages.push(message);
      };

      this.clearMessages = function () {
        $scope.messages.length = 0;
      };
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.text = '<div ng-init="a = 2" class="my-selector">\n    scope.a : [{{a}}]\n</div>';
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('myPreview', function ($compile) {
  return {
    require: '^myEditor',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, myEditorController) {
      scope.$watch(myEditorController.getText, function (newValue) {
        if (newValue !== undefined) {
          var e = angular.element('<div>' + newValue + '</div>');
          $compile(e)(scope);
          element.html(e);

          myEditorController.addMessage(
            'The value of "a" on the scope of the compiled element is: ' + 
            angular.element($('.my-selector')).scope().a)
        }
      });
    }    
  };
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.0.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.0-rc3-nonmin" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <my-editor></my-editor>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```